# Does Entity Framework make sense for smaller desktop applications?

Tags: c#, ios, .net, entity-framework, sqlite

I'm creating a relatively small database-based application (~20 tables and a maximum of 20K rows in the largest of them.  We're going with SQLite because we want to support Windows OS X, iPhone/iPad and Android and need to easily move the files around so SQLite is definitely the right choice.

Now in the past, I have simply used SQLite wrapper classes that pretty much do nothing except allow you to execute SQL against the database either as an action or as a query.  Nothing too fancy at all.

What I'm wondering is I see that Entity Framework also supports SQLite, at least on the Windows side of things.  I'm wondering if that makes more sense to use that or if I should just stick with the same, simple direct-SQL mode of things since I basically have to do that on the other platforms anyway.  But so many people I've talked to keep saying how great EF6.x is now.

I also remember our old ADO.NET Dataset days where we loved the visual designer of the DataSets for setting up tables, keys, relationships, etc. I'd love to have the ability to use that or something similar, but with the attributes such as [Table] and [Column] that I can use with my below code.

Thoughts?

### Update...

I know SQLite doesn't support Code First, but I've actually worked on a SQLiteContextInitializer that *does* allow me to do almost everything I need in a Code-first scenario.  Here it is for reference/enhancement.  I found someone else's version of something similar on the web and enhanced it to properly use the TableName attributes and such.  Enjoy!

```
class SqliteContextInitializer<T> : IDatabaseInitializer<T>
where T : SQLiteContext<T>
{
    private readonly bool _dbExists;
    private readonly DbModelBuilder _modelBuilder;

    public delegate void BeforeCreateDatabaseDelegate(DbModel model, out bool autoGenerateSchema);
    public readonly BeforeCreateDatabaseDelegate BeforeCreateDatabase;

    public delegate void AfterCreateDatabaseDelegate(DbModel model);
    public readonly AfterCreateDatabaseDelegate AfterCreateDatabase;

    public SqliteContextInitializer(string dbPath, DbModelBuilder modelBuilder, BeforeCreateDatabaseDelegate beforeCreateDatabase = null, AfterCreateDatabaseDelegate afterCreateDatabase = null)
    {
        _dbExists = File.Exists(dbPath);
        _modelBuilder = modelBuilder;
        BeforeCreateDatabase = beforeCreateDatabase;
        AfterCreateDatabase = afterCreateDatabase;
    }

    public void InitializeDatabase(T context)
    {
        if (_dbExists)
            return;

        var model = _modelBuilder.Build(context.Database.Connection);

        using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                bool autoGenerateSchema = true;

                if(BeforeCreateDatabase != null)
                    BeforeCreateDatabase(model, out autoGenerateSchema);

                if (autoGenerateSchema)
                {
                    AutoCreateSchema(context.Database, model);

                    if(AfterCreateDatabase != null)
                        AfterCreateDatabase(model);
                }

                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    class Index
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Table { get; set; }
        public List<string> Columns { get; set; }
    }

    private void AutoCreateSchema(Database db, DbModel model)
    {
        const string tableTemplate      = "CREATE TABLE [{0}] (\n{1}\n);";
        const string columnTemplate     = "    [{0}] {1} {2}"; // name, type, decl
        const string primaryKeyTemplate = "    PRIMARY KEY ({0})";
        const string foreignKeyTemplate = "    FOREIGN KEY ({0}) REFERENCES {1} ({2})";
        const string indexTemplate      = "CREATE INDEX {0} ON {1} ({2});";

        var indicies = new Dictionary<string, Index>();

        foreach (var tableInfo in model.StoreModel.EntityTypes)
        {
            var tableDefinitionRecords = new List<string>();

            // columns
            foreach (var columnInfo in tableInfo.Properties)
            {
                var columnDeclarations = new HashSet<string>();

                if (!columnInfo.Nullable)
                    columnDeclarations.Add("NOT NULL");

                var indexAnnotations = columnInfo.MetadataProperties
                    .Select(x => x.Value)
                    .OfType<IndexAnnotation>();

                foreach (var indexAnnotation in indexAnnotations)
                {
                    foreach (var indexAttribute in indexAnnotation.Indexes)
                    {
                        if (indexAttribute.IsUnique)
                            columnDeclarations.Add("UNIQUE");

                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(indexAttribute.Name))
                            continue;

                        Index index;
                        if (!indicies.TryGetValue(indexAttribute.Name, out index))
                        {
                            index = new Index
                            {
                                Name = indexAttribute.Name,
                                Table = tableInfo.Name,
                                Columns = new List<string>(),
                            };
                            indicies.Add(index.Name, index);
                        }
                        index.Columns.Add(columnInfo.Name);
                    }
                }

                // Add column definition record
                var columnDefinitionRecord = string.Format(columnTemplate,
                    columnInfo.Name, // Unlike with tables, this picks up the attribute-specified value
                    columnInfo.TypeName,
                    string.Join(" ", columnDeclarations));

                tableDefinitionRecords.Add(columnDefinitionRecord);
            }

            // primary keys
            if (tableInfo.KeyProperties.Any()) // then add primary key definition record
            {
                var primaryKeyColumnNames = tableInfo.KeyProperties.Select(x => x.Name);

                var primaryKeyRecord = string.Format(primaryKeyTemplate,
                    string.Join(", ", primaryKeyColumnNames));

                tableDefinitionRecords.Add(primaryKeyRecord);
            }

            // foreign keys
            foreach (var assoc in model.StoreModel.AssociationTypes)
            {
                if (assoc.Constraint.ToRole.Name == tableInfo.Name)
                {
                    var toKeyColumnNames = assoc.Constraint.ToProperties.Select(x => x.Name);
                    var fromKeyColumnNames = assoc.Constraint.FromProperties.Select(x => x.Name);

                    // Add foreign key definition record
                    var foreignKeyDefinitionRecord = string.Format(foreignKeyTemplate,
                        string.Join(", ", toKeyColumnNames),
                        assoc.Constraint.FromRole.Name,
                        string.Join(", ", fromKeyColumnNames));

                    tableDefinitionRecords.Add(foreignKeyDefinitionRecord);
                }
            }

            MetadataProperty tableNameProperty;
            var tableName = tableInfo.MetadataProperties.TryGetValue("TableName", true, out tableNameProperty)
                ? tableNameProperty.Value
                : tableInfo.Name;

            // Create table
            var sql = string.Format(tableTemplate,
                tableName,
                string.Join(",\n", tableDefinitionRecords));

            db.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
        }

        // create indexes for all tables
        foreach (var index in indicies.Values)
        {
            var columns = string.Join(", ", index.Columns);

            var sql = string.Format(indexTemplate,
                index.Name,
                index.Table,
                columns);

            db.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you planning to use code first, model first or database first? Are you doing TDD, Unit tests or integration tests?

Comment: I know SQLite/Entity doesn't support Code First, however I actually have already created a SQLiteContextInitializer that *does* do almost everything we need to in regards to creating a database from the models so we do have a rudimentary code-first ability with SQLite.  However, going back to our old ADO.NET Dataset days, we do love the visual designer of the DataSets for setting up tables, keys, relationships, etc.  I'd love to have the ability to use that, but with the attributes such as [Table] and [Column], etc.

Comment: You may want to consider using a micro-orm instead, e.g. Dapper, PetaPoco, ...

Comment: I second the vote for Dapper.  It's incredibly powerful and lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to use ORM. The question is which one?

Benefits of ORM:

- Reduced development time
- Developers can work in terms of a more application-centric object model
- Applications are freed from hard-coded dependencies on a particular data engine
- Language-Integrated Query support (called LINQ to Entities)

this is from here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937709.aspx

Comment: Do you mean micro-orm as it will be on a mobile device?

Comment: If Xamarin then SQLite.Net ORM.

Comment: Thanks, Xamarin and SQLite.Net have the [data annotations](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/sqlite-net). [SQLite.NET](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/data/part_3_using_sqlite_orm/) has [Table] and [Column].